# Royobi BP42 took off carb cleaned and new fuel lines now starts idols then shuts off but restarts again ould it be gasket where vacuum hole is

Tags: carburetor, gasket, fuel-pump

Removed carb cleaned reassembled with new fuel lines starts runs for awhile and dies but restarts gasket vacuum hole may be leaking

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you know that the gasket vacuum hole may be leaking.  Why don't you try fixing that and then see what happens?

Comment: Are you familiar with 2-stroke engines and how diaphragm carbs operate with crankcase pressure? You may need to review either the owner's manual or online sources of gas operated blower repairs. Basic 2-stroke fundamentals and understanding of diaphragm carbs can help solve this problem.